# How can we trigger the same request in Jmeter based on response from the request?

Tags: jmeter

I need to re-trigger the same request based on response from the request. IF the response contains different value which is not expected , i need to stop that re-trigger and should call the next request!

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Add to the request [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) which will check your response.

Now add again (Duplicate) the request with response assertion and then add your second request under While Controller - Can right click and choose Insert Parent. in the Condition field add `${__jexl3("${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}" == "false")}` which will continue until request is success.

Now request will be sent and while response assertion failed it will keep sending the request.

[image]

Comment: i tried with your response. See the image here https://imgur.com/M0Ic6h5

In GetCategorybyID -> Looking for Some Asertions -> If True Again i need to Call the same request by passing different value from the response ( from the first request). Need to continue this process until i reach to the point where the **Call the same request by passing different value** gets failed

Comment: so add regular expression as post processor that will override variable with the new value

Comment: I am trying to do here is that
Get Category BY ID -> RESPONSE (CHECK whether if it has sub category or not )
If RESPONSE (CHECK whether if it has sub category or not ) = TRUE 
Again Pick random Category ID by passing different parameter- > RESPONSE (CHECK whether if it has sub category or not )
IF YES again do the above process again, else Get the Product details from the last fetched Category 

Hope it is clear !!

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your request under [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) and use condition like:

   ```
   ${__javaScript("${myVar}" != "some value",)}
   ```
2. Add a relevant JMeter [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) as a child of the request and configure it to extract the "interesting" value into the `myVar` variable.

JMeter will run While Controller's child(ren) in the loop and will break when `${myVar}` variable value becomes `some value`.